# Card view where each corner has different radius

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This is what i do to create a card view.

```
class Card: UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 3

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 3
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor.gray
    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
        layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath

    }
}
```

But this is not what i want, what I want is a card view where the corner radius of each side is different say top left has 5 bottom left has 10 top right has 20 bottom left has corner radius of 30.
I have also tried this,

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.myview.bounds, byRoundingCorners:.topLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize.init(width: 60, height:0))
let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
self.myView.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

But here is the problem this is how it looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrDKm.png

this is how it should be

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa52p.png
this is how it looks without the UIBezierPath
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6OTc.png

Comment: Have you seen [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624358-bezierpathwitharccenter)?

Comment: @paulvs please do revisit my question